# add infinite loop function with reset on series of animations with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function ani() {
  if(!$(':animated').length) {

    $('#img1, #img2, #img3').css({
      width: '50px',
      left: '112px',
      top: '212px',
      display: 'none',
      position: 'absolute'
    });      
    $('#img4, #img5, #img6').css({
      width: '50px',
      left: '112px',
      top: '212px',
      display: 'none',
      position: 'absolute'
    });  
    $('#img7, #img8, #img9, #img10').css({
      left: '358px';
      top: '212px',
      display: 'none',
      position: 'absolute'
    });  

    $("#img1").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 
    $("#img2").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 
    $("#img3").delay(1000).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 

    $("#img4").delay(200).fadeIn().animate({opacity: .9, top:"400px"},'fast', ani);
    $("#img5").delay(700).fadeIn().animate({opacity: .9, top:"400px"},'fast', ani);
    $("#img6").delay(1100).fadeIn().animate({opacity: .9, top:"400px"},'fast', ani);

    $("#img7").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani);
    $("#img8").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani);
    $("#img9").delay(1000).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani);
    $("#img10").delay(1100).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 
  }
};

ani();
```

Wondering how to incorporate a infinite or a defined amount of times for my animations to loop in jQuery.. Currently the above just executes once.

**It needs to be the same original animation not progressing lower down the screen in masses. So reset and then replay; the user would see as it was on first view.**

Comment: Infinite loop should be achieved with CSS3 animation instead.

Comment: put it in a function, and when all of the animations are complete, run it again...

Comment: Just tried updated above.. it didn't work

Comment: Do you want to determine when all animations are complete, and *then* start the animations again?

Comment: Yes. How could I do that

Comment: I would like to point the fact that the `animation()` function is called during the `fadeIn()` function. You should execute the animation in the callback function of the `fadeIn()` function.

Comment: I just tried set Interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function as the callback for all animations, and always check for `$(':animated').length`.  This will ensure that it runs after the last animation has completed.

You can also reset the `css` each time the function runs:

```
function ani() {
  if(!$(':animated').length) {
    $('img').css({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      display: 'none'
    });      
    $("#img1").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 
    $("#img2").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 
    $("#img3").delay(1000).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 

    $("#img4").delay(200).fadeIn().animate({opacity: .9, top:"400px"},'fast', ani);
    $("#img5").delay(700).fadeIn().animate({opacity: .9, top:"400px"},'fast', ani);
    $("#img6").delay(1100).fadeIn().animate({opacity: .9, top:"400px"},'fast', ani);

    $("#img7").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani);
    $("#img8").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani);
    $("#img9").delay(1000).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani);
    $("#img10").delay(1100).fadeIn().animate({left: '+=-100', top: '+=200'}, 200, ani); 
  }
};

ani();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zqc2v8oj/1)

Comment: Yes. But it needs to be the same original animation not progressing lower down the screen. So reset and replay as it would on first view.

Comment: This works however is not desired result. I need to reset and replay original animation not duplicate it and watch it grow down the screen.

Comment: Thanks, Updated my code in question -- still isn't resetting

Comment: You have a semicolon instead of a comma here:  `left: '358px';`.  Otherwise, seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/4bv2zf8x/1/

Comment: OK. Thanks, this works stand alone. But I have a 'replay' button and this doesn't replay after this button is clicked.

Comment: You could stop all the animations when it's clicked.  See http://jsfiddle.net/4bv2zf8x/2/

Comment: Thank you, Lindsey brohaan.